# Como obtener booleano de dataframe. Simplemente su valor, no su tipo, ni su número de fila

Tags: python, pandas

Porque al imprimir el booleano me dice el num de fila y el tipo?

```
cod = wod_ejs.loc[r]['codigo']
v = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['vueltas']
p = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['porcentaje']
c = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['cap']
m = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['material']

print('\nWOD %d - Vueltas:%d - CAP:%d\' - [%d] - Código: %s - Material: %s' % (r + 1, v, c, p*100, cod, m))
```

Resultado:

```
WOD 3 - Vueltas:4 - CAP:30' - [80] - Código: w0003 - Material: 2    False
Name: material, dtype: bool
```

¿Porque en los otros me muestra el valor que yo busco y en este me lo trata como un objeto y me da más info?

Pensaba que era por ser tipo booleano, pero aún convirtiendo m a cadena de caracteres sigue haciendo lo mismo.

**EDITO PARA APORTAR MÁS INFO**

Mi código:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data/wod.csv')
wod = pd.DataFrame(data)
data = pd.read_csv('data/wod_ejs.csv')
wod_ejs = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('Hay',shape[0],'WODs registrados')

""" Este bucle tiene como finalidad recorrer cada fila del dataframe, pues
cada fila será un "wod" diferente y para cada fila se van a realizar
diferentes acciones. """

shape = wod_ejs.shape
for r in range(0, shape[0]):
    cod = wod_ejs.loc[r]['codigo']
    v = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['vueltas']
    p = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['porcentaje']
    c = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['cap']
    m = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['material']

    print('\nWOD %d - Vueltas:%d - CAP:%d\' - [%d] - Código: %s - Material: %s' % (r + 1, v, c, p*100, cod, m))
```

A continuación dejo un ejemplo de lo que yo quiero que salga:

```
WOD 1 - Vueltas:3 - CAP:30' - [60] - Código: w0001 - Material: True
WOD 2 - Vueltas:2 - CAP:30' - [75] - Código: w0002 - Material: True
WOD 3 - Vueltas:4 - CAP:30' - [80] - Código: w0003 - Material: False
```

Luego con estos datos querré ir trabajándolos e ir extrayendo más información.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

En general lo que obtienes al hacer `wod[wod['codigo']==cod]` es una serie. No tienes por qué suponer que tenga un solo elemento pues puede haber en general varias filas que repitan el mismo código en la columna `'codigo'`.

Entiendo que en tu caso cada `cod` aparece una sola vez en tu dataframe, pero aún así el resultado será una serie, si bien la serie resultante tendrá un solo elemento.

En general, puedes obtener los elementos de la serie como lista accediendo al atributo `values`. Es decir, por ejemplo, `m.values` te dará una lista con los valores de la serie que obtuviste en la variable `m`. Si en tu caso esta serie tiene un solo elemento, puedes sacarlo con `m.values[0]`. De este modo ya tienes un valor escalar en vez de una serie.

Entiendo que al usar `%d` como parte de tu cadena de formato, pandas posiblemente está haciendo todo esto que acabo de describir (tomar el primer dato de la serie), pero al usar `%s` en cambio intenta representar la serie completa como cadena, dándote el resultado que observas. La forma más genérica de hacer lo que buscas entiendo que sería:

```py
cod = wod_ejs.loc[r]['codigo']
v = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['vueltas'].values[0]
p = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['porcentaje'].values[0]
c = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['cap'].values[0]
m = wod[wod['codigo'] == cod]['material'].values[0]

print('\nWOD %d - Vueltas:%d - CAP:%d\' - [%d] - Código: %s - Material: %s' % (r + 1, v, c, p*100, cod, m))
```

Aún así estoy convencido de que debe de haber una forma más "pythónica" (o "pandónica" en este caso) de conseguir lo que quieres, sólo que no tengo claro qué quieres exactamente. Me da la sensación de que el código que pones forma parte de un bucle en el que iteras sobre `r`. En general muy pocas veces es necesario iterar sobre un dataframe, y siempre hay una forma mejor de hacer que pandas itere por tí con sus operaciones vectorizadas, que son mucho más rápidas.

Si editas la pregunta para mostrar un fragmento de tu dataframe de entrada y de lo que pretendes obtener como salida, podría orientarte sobre cómo lograrlo con las funciones de pandas.

Comment: Efectivamente, itero en un bucle jajaja. Mi primer objetivo era que funcionara y ahora estoy intentando dejarlo "mejor" poco a poco y por ello las preguntas. Ahora edito mi pregunta